# Add un text onto an image programmatically using Kotlin

Tags: android, image, kotlin, text

I have a image "myXmlImage" in my .xml file

In the .kt file, I want to paste another "newImage" image as well as a little text "newText".

```
myXmlImage.setImageDrawable(newImage.drawable)
myXmlImage.imageMatrix = newImage.imageMatrix
```

So far it has been working very well and the new image is in place.

I'm completely stuck on how to paste the little "newText" into it

Any ideas will be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps there's more than what you've described here. But if those are really your only specifications, then what you're asking for is really easy.

I'm assuming that your xml file has a root of ConstraintLayout. If it doesn't, then you're going to either want to change it or at least wrap your ImageView inside of a ConstraintLayout.

1. Use the layout editor to place a TextView inside of your ImageView (NOT AS A CHILD; when I say "inside", I mean spacially inside). If you haven't used the layout editor very much, it might take you a couple of tries to place the TextView inside. Don't just drag it into the ImageView as if it were a child. Drag it and drop it under the ImageView inside of the ConstraintLayout and then use little circles on the sides to attach it to the sides of the ImageView. Don't forget to set the text of the TextView as "".
2. (I'm not actually sure if this step is necessary because I don't know what the default background of a TextView is, but I do it out of habit.)When you're done placing that TextView inside of the ImageView, go the code of your xml file and use android:background="#00FFFFFF" (or maybe somewhere in your project you have either a transparent background drawable or a transparent @color that you can reference by name).
3. I'm sure you know the rest. Just give that TextView an Id like newtext and inside of your activity retrieve the view: newText:TextView=findViewById(R.id.newtext). And then set the text: newText.text="new text".

Comment: Yes of course pffff, thanks D. Kupra. I'll try tomorrow morning, I think it will not be easy to make that textView under the imageView but with a little patience... Have a nice day. Another layout for a fragment is over that imageView :-)

Comment: Well it's pretty surprising what you can accomplish by giving things high elevation and then toggling their visibility. I'm not sure how expensive it is rendering wise, but I have at least 5 or 6 activities that test well on devices, and the only way I can get the effect that I want is by stacking views inside the same parent, stacking their elevations, and then toggling their visibilities at runtime.

Comment: Yes it's very interesting. I'm new on Android, coming from iOS. It works perfectly, thanks again. You said "elevation", did you mean it's possible to bring a element on front on the stack (stacked images)?

Comment: Yeah, it's right there along with the other android:background=.... tags inside the xml underneath the view. Whenever you want a view to not get covered up by other views, just set the elevation higher. And the cool thing is you can abuse that trick as much as you want. Set one view's elevation as 5 while another view is invisible, and then set the invisible view's elevation to 10 and it will show up on top whenever you decide to make it visible.